# Linking Files dynamically

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

We have a Mac OS X app that tags various folders & files from around the system. If you click any of these "bookmarked" files, it will open.

Problem:
When one of these files is renamed, the app can't find them anymore.

Question:
How can we link these files dynamically, so they will still work even after move or rename ?
Like a hard link or alias ?

Thanks

Comment: I was about to answer than you could store the device ID and inode (see stat(2)) instead of the filename, but couldn't come up with a solution to get the filename back from the dev/inode in order to open the file/folder.

Comment: Thanks for the try. It would be great if there were a api to get for each file a fileID that one could just store, instead of the path .. Well maybe there's a workaround with the filesystem api
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the "Locating Files Using Bookmarks" section of [Accessing Files and Directories](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html).

Comment: Thanks, great answer !
I also found this: File Events API to track changes, but I guess URL is easier
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html